# AngularJS model-bind not working if the model and bind are set by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, dynamic

I am learning Angular JS and I am stuck at a pretty basic step.

Here is my test code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            function enable()
            {
                $("#test_model").attr("data-ng-model", "test");
                $("#test_bind").attr("data-ng-bind", "test");
            };
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div data-ng-app="">
            <div>
                <input type=text id=test_model />
            </div>

            <div>
                <p id=test_bind></p>
            </div>

            <button onclick=enable()>Enable</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here, what I expect to happen is, when the **Enable** button is clicked, it should enable the bind, and so if anything is typed into the `#test_model` input, it should update `#test_bind` paragraph. But it is not working.

I can see with Firebug that the attributes (`data-ng-model` and `data-ng-bind`) are being updated when the **Enable** button is clicked, but it is not taking effect as it would if it were statically coded (hard-coding the model and bind parameters).

If I code it statically, then I notice that 3 new classes (`ng-pristine`, `ng-untouched` and `ng-valid`) are automatically added to `#test_model` and one new class (`ng-binding`) is added to `#test_bind`. So I changed my `enable()` function to this:

```
function enable()
{
    $("#test_model").attr("data-ng-model", "test");
    $("#test_bind").attr("data-ng-bind", "test");

    $("#test_model").addClass("ng-pristine");
    $("#test_model").addClass("ng-untouched");
    $("#test_model").addClass("ng-valid");

    $("#test_bind").addClass("ng-binding");
};
```

But still, not working.

What am I missing?

Comment: Dont mix Angular and jQuery like this. You need to check out the `$compile` service.

Comment: Oh! Can you please tell me where it gets messed up if it is mixed?

Comment: jQuery and angular works very different from each other, drop the jQuery completely or you will have a lot of issues like that

Comment: The issue is, I already have a full jQuery app. I want to add a new Angular feature to it. Anyways, thanks for the advice. I guess I need to find an Angular-only solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to dynamically add Angular directives like ng-model, ng-bind etc.
you must create your own directive and use [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile).

You can use angular ng-show or ng-switch to switch showing DOM elements without bindings and elements with ng-model and other attributes that you need.